# Why does this FileStream only return zeroes?

Tags: c#, filestream

I've got a file (test.txt) which contains "1234567". However when I try to read it on C# using FileStream.Read, I get only 0s (seven zeroes in this case). Could anyone tell me why? I'm really lost here.

**Edit:** Problem solved, wrong comparision operator. However now it's returning "49505152535455"

**Edit 2:** Done. For the record, I had to output the *byte* variable as a *char*.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        FileStream fil = null;

        try
        {
            fil = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[fil.Length];
            int toRead = (int)fil.Length;
            int Read = 0;

            while (toRead < 0)
            {
                int n = fil.Read(bytes, Read, toRead);

                Read += n;
                toRead -= n;
            }

            //Tried this, will only return 0000000
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                Console.Write(b.ToString());
            }


        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oops! {0}", exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            fil.Close();
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
while (toRead < 0)
```

makes sure you never actually read. toRead will be >= 0 before the loop.

Afterwards you dump the byte array that was never filled.

Comment: Thank you. However, now it's returning "49505152535455".

Comment: Clearly it has something to do with the character encoding or something: 49 50 51 52 53 54 55

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach (byte b in bytes)
            {
                Console.Write(b.ToString());
            }
```

This code is incorrect.  It is printing the string value of the byte's value.  ie 49 for the ascii char '0', 50 for '1', etc.

You need to output it as

```
Console.Write(new Char(b).toString());
```

Comment: Or better still: Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));

Comment: Why would that be 'incorrect'? That totally depends on the intention.

Comment: It was incorrect, and Mike got the idea right. However that didn't compile, I had to cast b as a char instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, been a while since I have worked in C# and was trying to remember the exact conversion.

Answer (score 1):

while (toRead < 0) should be while (toRead > 0)  (greater than)